# Find eigenvectors of $T: \mathbb{C}_n[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_n[x], (T(p))(x)=p’(x)+p(0) \cdot x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I would like to find the eigenvectors of the linear transformation $(T(p)(x))=p’(x)+p(0)
\cdot x^n$ over $\mathbb{C}_n[x]$. I’ve tried treating it as a differential equation but didn’t get far. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: here $\mathbb{C}_n[x]$ represents the vector space of polynomials up to degree $n$ with complex coefficients

Comment: is $\mathbb{C}_n[x]$ polynomials of at most degree $n$ with complex coefficients?

Comment: @podiki Indeed, I’ll edit the question to add that

Comment: Are you considering $\mathbb C_n[x]$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ or over $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I'd recommend you write out the definition of a general polynomial $p$ in terms of its coefficients and then match coefficients in the equation $T(p)=\lambda p$. You'll likely have to consider a few cases, but each one shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I don't think you should think of this as a differential equation. More like a linear system of equations with the coefficients of the eigenpolynomial as the unknowns. Or, just write down the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the monomial basis.

Comment: Hint: $T^n = n! I_{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p_k(x)=x^k$, $k=0,1,\cdots,n$.
Clearly
$$\{p_0(x),p_1(x),\cdots,p_n(x)\}$$
is a basis of $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Note
$$ (Tp_k)(x)=p_k'(x)+p_k(0)x^n=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
x^n &\text{ if }k=0,\\
kx^{k-1}&\text{ if }k\ge1,
\end{array}=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
p_n(x) &\text{ if }k=0,\\
kp_{k-1}(x)&\text{ if }k\ge1.
\end{array}\right.\right.
$$
Let $P=(p_0,p_1,\cdots,p_n)^T$
and then
$$ TP=AP $$
where
$$ A=\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&\cdots&0&1 \\
1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&2&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
0&0&\cdots&n&0
\end{matrix}\right). $$
Then the characteristic equation of $A$ is
$$ \det(\lambda I_{n+1}-A)=\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda&0&\cdots&0&-1 \\
-1&\lambda&\cdots&0&0\\
0&-2&\cdots&0&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
0&0&\cdots&\lambda&0 \\
0&0&\cdots&-n&\lambda
\end{matrix}\right)=\lambda^{n+1}+n!=0. $$
So the eigenvalues of $T$ or $A$ is $\lambda_k=\lambda_k=(n!)^{\frac1{n+1}}e^{\frac{k\pi }{n+1}i}$, $k=0,1,\cdots,n$. Solving
$$ (A-\lambda_kI_{n+1})X=0 $$
will give
$$ X_k=\bigg(1,\frac{1!}{\lambda_k}, \frac{2!}{\lambda_k^2},\cdots, \frac{(n-1)!}{\lambda_k^{n-1}},\lambda_k\bigg)^T $$
for $k=0,1,\cdots,n$.